# Upgrading to ActionText - editor not working/appearing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actiontext

I'm trying to implement ActionText on my app that's been upgraded to Rails 6.0.1.

I ran `rails action_text:install` and migrated, then added `has_rich_text :content` to my `comment` model. Then in the form I've switched `f.text_area :content` to `f.rich_text_area :content`.

However the editor that appears looks like this and can't attach files. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem after upgrading from Rails 5.2 to Rails 6.0. Please add the following line in your application.scss:

> @import 'trix/dist/trix.css'
>
> @import 'actiontext'

checkout these blogs for more details:

[https://blog.rubynetti.it/i/how-to-add-action-text-in-rails-6:](https://blog.rubynetti.it/i/how-to-add-action-text-in-rails-6)

https://blog.francium.tech/action-text-in-rails-6-a-brief-intro-dd33fb412eb5

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 6.1
Webpacker
Tailwind 2.1 with JIT

I added `@import 'trix/dist/trix.css';` to `application.scss` to have Trix working as expected.

Comment: #same. Installing ActionText to a rails 6.1 app with Webpacker and Bootstrap 5.0.0-beta3, the "actiontext.css" import wasn't necessary. I only needed to import 'trix/dist/trix.css'; to application.scss to correct the control bar formatting.

Answer (score 2):

you can refer to this : https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/2059

basically the build chain works like this:

```
(if extract_css == true) -> application stylesheet -> MiniCssExtractPlugin -> application.css -> stylesheet_pack_tag 'application'

(if extract_css == false) -> application stylesheet -> style-loader -> application.js (loads css in head)
```

So that if you want to use `stylesheet_pack_tag` then following steps maybe help you:

1. set `extract_css: true` for development in `webpacker.yml`
2. `@import "trix/dist/trix";` into `javascript/stylesheets/application.scss`
3. `import "../stylesheets/application";` into
   `javascript/stylesheets/application.js`
4. `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` into `application.html.erb`
5. run `./bin/webpack` && `rails s`

Answer (score 1):

The one part I was missing after upgrading was this:

`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>`

Mine is placed in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Just make sure it is included somewhere.

It it isn't that, check to make sure the stylesheets for actiontext are being included as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this resolved by adding

`@import "trix/dist/trix.css";`

to **application.scss** because I am in the full doubt that **actiontext.scss** *line no 6*

```
//= require trix/dist/trix
```

is also does the same but not sure why it's not pulling the css.

**SOLUTION** -  Add `@import "trix/dist/trix.css";` to application.scss.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem of the rich text areas not showing, you probably need to add <%= javascript_pack_tag "application" %> if you're loading assets with Webpack, <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> if using asset pipeline (as someone helpfully recommended in my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070034/rails-6-actiontext-rich-text-area-works-normally-does-not-appear-when-rendered/59071291#59071291)).

But I'm not sure this will fix the toolbar button styling, since I still have that issue. Will come back to this if I find a fix.

**EDIT** I have fixed the broken styling by adding the full contents of the [trix editor stylesheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/basecamp/trix/master/dist/trix.css) to the actiontext.scss file then explicitly pulling  the stylesheet into my layout file with <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'actiontext' %> note: doing it this way you will also have to define it in your assets precompile line in config/initializers/assets.rb line:

`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( sidenav.css editor.css form.css actiontext.css )`

Answer (score 0):

##### Solution for rails 7

Add `actiontext` to the top of application.scss

```
@import "actiontext.css";

...
...
...
```

[Also you can find more details here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43441)

**Be careful** using `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "actiontext", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>` in your layout for solving this issue. In my case, this was a reason why `link_to` triggered `GET` request twice.

Answer (score 0):

in Rails 7 with `cssbundling-rails`

I needed to rename `actiontext.css` to `actiontext.scss`

Then I added `@import './actiontext.scss';` in `application.scss` file.

Again: `actiontext` file should have `.scss` extension

**actiontext.scss file:**

```
/*
 * Provides a drop-in pointer for the default Trix stylesheet that will format the toolbar and
 * the trix-editor content (whether displayed or under editing). Feel free to incorporate this
 * inclusion directly in any other asset bundle and remove this file.
 *
 *= require trix
*/

/*
 * We need to override trix.css’s image gallery styles to accommodate the
 * <action-text-attachment> element we wrap around attachments. Otherwise,
 * images in galleries will be squished by the max-width: 33%; rule.
*/
.trix-content .attachment-gallery > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery > .attachment {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  max-width: 33%;
}

.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--2 > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--2 > .attachment, .trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--4 > action-text-attachment,
.trix-content .attachment-gallery.attachment-gallery--4 > .attachment {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.trix-content action-text-attachment .attachment {
  padding: 0 !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```